# flutter navigator router without onpressed

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, router, navigator

I have a router class in my project and I want to use addresses in the router in it. I know I should use a navigator. push(context, my router ) but I want to use this without onpressed or onTap. and I want to return the widget.
here is my class router:

```
Map<String, WidgetBuilder> routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
  '/firstPage': (context) => const FirstPage(),
  
  '/': (context) => const BottomNavBar( activeTabIndex: 0),
  '/exploreHome/podcastsProfile': (context) =>PodcastsProfile(podId: exploreManager.podId),
  '/exploreHome/morepagepod': (context) =>MorePod(moreId: exploreManager.moreId,showProfilePodcasts: exploreManager.showProfilePodcasts),
  '/exploreHome/morepageepd': (context) =>MoreEpd(moreId: exploreManager.moreId ),
};
```

i want to use router class instead of call directly my classes :

use `'/exploreHome/podcastsProfile'` instead of `PodcastsProfile(podId: podId);`

```
 Widget renderBody(String page) {
    Widget widget = Container();
    switch (page) {
      case podcastsProfile:
        widget = **PodcastsProfile(
          podId: podId,
        );**
    }
    return Container();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` as a hack to trigger a route, or any imperative code, after the frame has been rendered.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html

That said, it's a hack and I would suggest re-thinking how you got here. How did the String `page` become part of the build method? Could you react when the `page` state changed instead of in the build method? My two cents.